# Can we GPU for normal opration?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

Here is Thing.

I bought MSI laptop which is very good for Gaming.

I am doing some work on same laptop, which required for more processing power. MSI laptop has NVIDIA's GeForce GTX 1050 GPU 4GB card which dedicated for Graphic.

I know GPU is mostly used for Graphic stuffs and it is faster than CPU(which is intel's core I5 7th Gen).

But is there is any chance that I can use my GPU for my processing which is not related with Graphic.

Thanks :) ...

Comment: It depends on the specifics of "my processing". Some jobs can be relegated to the GPU, but not others.

Comment: Naive answer: no, probably not.

Comment: I am doing TCPDUMP for all the hosts within a network(I am also doing tucpdump operation of all interfaces in hosts.). In my network there are 20+ hosts , I am running different process for each host and different thread for each interface also along that I am running other operation to collects stats. I am just think can I use GPU for stats collection and CPU for TCPDUMP. ?